# Actions executed multiple time iBeacon

Tags: swift, ibeacon

I'm playing with iBeacons and I would like to execute a function or command only one time when a specific beacon is in the range. Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/Silvering/f3dc4edf32eb55afe433
When the beacon is in the range, I receive "Its the purple" x10000
I only want to display this message one time.. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, there are basically 2 things you can do

- Remove location delegate after you locate your beacon, so you will not receive any more calls
- Remember that you already located that beacon (for example, in some array) and expand your logic with condition that will skip it in case that it should be presented multiple time.

So something like:

```
// Create storage for located beacons
var locatedBeacons = [Int]()

// Adds beacon to storage
func beaconLocated(beaconId : Int) {  
    self.locatedBeacons.append(beaconId)
}

// Already located?
func isBeaconLocated(beaconId : Int) -> Bool {
    return contains(self.locatedBeacons, beaconId)
}
```

Comment: Good answer!  I typically use a NSDictionary to store the located beacons (keyed by a string that is a combination of UUID/major/minor), as the locatedBeacons array will allow multiple entries for the same beacon.

Comment: However you will implement the solution, I just tried to give you general idea about how you could do it -  what you do is obviously much better.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jiri, I try it now I keep you inform.

Comment: Jiri here is my code updated : https://gist.github.com/Silvering/c78967c82e82c1308770 However the function FilterAction1() is still executed multiple time... Maybe I'm wrong somewhere.

Comment: if isBeaconLocated(table1[0]) == true should probably be == false, right? if you want it only for the first time.. :) Also, move the filter before you write that you located the beacon (just switch last two code blocks), otherwise it will not work..

Comment: also just a small piece of advice, just use isBeaconLocated or !isBeaconLocated instead of == true / == false, it makes your code more readable :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Jiri, it works when I have only one beacon and action. Now I would like to do the same but with many beacons and many actions. Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/Silvering/a8d63511fb80e43e81d2 My problem is that I receive many times "Beacon 2" or "Beacon 3"... I don't understand why..